# Dirent iteration in C on linux

Tags: c, dirent.h

I am trying to go through a directory and when encountering a text file I want to open it. For some reason I am getting a null condition on the while loop before I hit a text file so it exits early and I am not sure why.

https://ideone.com/7iHTK1

The loop condition

```
while ((pDirent = readdir(pDir)) != NULL)
{
    printf("*******");
    printf("The filePath is: %s \n", filePath);
    printf("dirent is %s \n", pDirent->d_name);
    if (strcmp(pDirent->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(pDirent->d_name, "..") == 0)
    {
        printf("get that shit %s\n", pDirent->d_name);
        continue;
    }
    strcat(filePath, pDirent->d_name);
    printf ("[%s]\n", filePath);
    printf("Is regular? %d \n", IsRegularFile(filePath));
    printf("Is dir? %d \n", isDirectory(filePath));
    strcat(filePath, "/");
    printf("%c %c %c \n",filePath[strlen(filePath) - 4], filePath[strlen(filePath) - 3],filePath[strlen(filePath) - 2]);
    if (filePath[strlen(filePath) - 4] == 't' && filePath[strlen(filePath) - 3] == 'x' && filePath[strlen(filePath) - 2] == 't') //add check for length and .txt
    {
        printf("File is txt\n");
        break;
    }
    printf("end of loop\n");
}
```

is met and then it exits. I have the file structure:

testDir(testDir1)

testDir1(testDir1-2)

testDir1-2(testFile.txt)

basically it gets to testDir1-2 and then it exits the loops, my filepath is testDir/testDir1/testDir1-2 and it never gets the testFile.txt for some reason. The pDirent->d_name is null as well.

Comment: Suggestion: posting all the relevant portions of the code will help you get a faster response.  In this case you must have code to recurse through the directory structure.

Comment: @user3386109 That would be what my loop does, but really for now it just finds a txt and then exits the loops. Which doesn't seem to be working for some reason.

Comment: what does the debugger say?

Comment: looks like u are expecting readdir to recurse into child dirs - it does not

Comment: @pm100 I get a Segmentation fualt, can you explain what you mean by child directors? What does readir do? How can I go through like I want to?

Comment: Is 'filepath' large enough to hold the data you're appending?

Comment: I got it mostly working, I was cating / onto the filePath when it could still be a text file making it unreadable. It works now for them most part.

Answer (score 1):

You are not updating the directory. You must use recursion to update the directory and use a loop to iterate the current directory.

```
#define is_regular 0100000

    void scan (const char* directory)
    {
        DIR* pdir = opendir (directory); 
        
        dirent *pent = NULL;
    
        
    
        while (pent = readdir (pdir)) 
        {
    
            if (pent->d_name[0] == '.')
                continue;
            
    
            char* fileName = (char*) malloc(strlen(directory) + strlen(pent->d_name) + 2);
            strcpy(fileName,directory);
            strcat(fileName, "/");
            strcat(fileName, pent->d_name);
    
            struct stat st;
            stat(fileName, &st);
            
            if (st.st_mode & is_regular)
            {
                //get the file, check whether a txt or not
            }
            else
            {
                scan (fileName);
            }
            
        }
    }
```